# Overlaying a package with "cmake" build type

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-make-isolated, ompl, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit:** I think the final answer to this question was basically, "This is expected. Don't worry about it."

---

I want to overlay the ompl package, which is a cmake-only build: `<buildtool_depend>cmake</buildtool_depend>` . I follow the steps according to the [workspace overlaying tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/ompl-ws/src && cd ~/ompl-ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ git clone git@github.com:ros-gbp/ompl-release.git ompl
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make_isolated  # "isolated" is needed for cmake-only builds.
$ source devel_isolated/setup.zsh  # I use zsh.
$ rospack find ompl
/opt/ros/hydro/share/ompl
```

At this point, I would expect `rospack find ompl` to return `~/ompl-ws/src/ompl`, but it does not. That's because the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` hasn't been updated. In fact, here's the setup file (`devel_isolated/ompl/setup.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin.builder module

# remember type of shell if not already set
if [ -z "$CATKIN_SHELL" ]; then
  CATKIN_SHELL=sh
fi
# detect if running on Darwin platform
_UNAME=`uname -s`
IS_DARWIN=0
if [ "$_UNAME" = "Darwin" ]; then
  IS_DARWIN=1
fi

# Prepend to the environment
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH"
if [ $IS_DARWIN -eq 0 ]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
else
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
fi
export PATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl/bin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/devel_isolated/ompl/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

This is very different from the normal setup file! Even when I put a normal setup file in there, it still doesn't work, because it's not a catkin build (it doesn't have a `.catkin` file, which is what `_setup_util.py` looks for). If I use [workspace chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces) to build something else that depends on ompl, it *does* use the overlayed version, but it makes me nervous because it doesn't *say* it's using the overlaid version, and `rospack find` still points to the system version:

```
# It says:
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
# It SHOULD say:
-- This workspace overlays: /home/<user>/ompl-ws/devel_isolated;/opt/ros/hydro
```

**Is this normal?? What's the correct way to overlay a cmake-only package?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208870/overlaying-a-package-with-%22cmake%22-build-type/) by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> At this point, I would expect rospack find ompl to return ~/ompl-ws/src/ompl, but it does not. That's because the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH hasn't been updated.

`ompl` isn't a ROS package, and therefore does not directly or indirectly depend on or find_package `roslib` which is the package which sets the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

The `setup.*sh` files are normally generated by each catkin package, but since `ompl` doesn't find_package `catkin` and doesn't call `catkin_package` in its CMake, it doesn't generate any `setup.*sh` files. So, `catkin_make_isolated` places basic `setup.*sh` files on behalf of the package.

A reasonably simple workaround is to clone a copy of catkin into the workspace with `ompl`. This is quick and it will ensure that `setup.*sh` are generated by `catkin_make*` commands.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-05-09**:
By "clone a copy of catkin into the workspace" did you mean just `git clone git@github.com:ros/catkin.git` and re-run `catkin_make_isolated`?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-05-09**:
Just clone it into your "source" space, usually the `src` folder in your workspace.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-05-09**:
Yeah, doing that with any random catkin package will correctly overlay that package, but only that package is added to the package path and ompl is still missing: `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ntraft/Development/ompl-ws/src/catkin:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks`.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-05-09**:
It's still added to all those other paths, as shown above, but it's just missing from the package path. Not sure if that's fine or if it will cause errors at some point.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-05-10**:
As I said, `ompl` is not a ROS package, and because of that it does not directly or indirectly depend on `roslib`. Only packages which directly or indirectly depend on and find package `roslib` get added to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.